# How to show something before TabLayoutPanel?

Tags: java, gwt

I want to add a header to my application (an image) before the tabs. I'm using a TabLayoutPanel inside a RootLayoutPanel.
I tried to add something first using a VerticalPanel then the TabLayoutPanel but I only got the Tabs shown, the content of the TabLayoutPanel disappeared (all the widgets I have there).
I tried LayoutPanel but that showed the image in the background behind the TabLayoutPanel, the tabs are still on the top of the page.

```
private final TabLayoutPanel tabPanel = new TabLayoutPanel(2.4, Unit.EM);
private final RootLayoutPanel rootPanel = RootLayoutPanel.get();

//I want to add something before this using some panel
//add(new HTML("<div id=\"banner\">HI THIS SHOULD BE AT THE TOP<div>")
rootPanel.add(tabPanel);
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: You are certainly doing something wrong, but we cannot help without seeing the code.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't know how to do that correctly, I don't know what kind of panel should I use to add something before the tabLayoutPanel :S

Answer (score 0):

oh the problem was with the Height thing in the TabLayoutPanel, setting it to 2.4 didn't allow anything before it to appear!
so I solved that by doing

```
private final TabLayoutPanel tabPanel = new TabLayoutPanel(10, Unit.EM);
private final RootLayoutPanel rootPanel = RootLayoutPanel.get();
private final LayoutPanel layoutPanel = new LayoutPanel();
layoutPanel.add(new HTML("<div id=\"banner\">HI THIS SHOULD BE AT THE TOP<div>"));
rootPanel.add(layoutPanel);
rootPanel.add(tabPanel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at HeaderPanel?

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HeaderPanel.html

Not the most helpful name but I think it does what you want.